# Add a row with sum of a column value in Laravel Datatable column using Yajra Datatable

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I am using Yajra Datatable in my laravel project.

I want to add a footer that will show the total of a specific column value.
How can I set this footer in the blade file and pass the sum from the controller?

Answer (score 0):

it is not necessary to do the sum from the controller, datatables can do the sum from the view but only if the processing is on the client side, I leave you the documentation with the example I hope it helps you: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html